# Can't get the react router to work in my Symfony app

Tags: reactjs, symfony, routes

Can't get this router-thing to work. This is what I have:

Symfony controller looking like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, $slug = null)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ));
}


/**
 * @Route("/projects", name="projects")
 */
public function projectsAction(Request $request)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}
```

This actions both renders the same twig-page which renders this react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './home.jsx';
import Projects from './projects.jsx';

class Base extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
          Blablablabla......
          a menu and some stuff blablablabla....

          <div className="row" id="mainContent">
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <Switch>
                     <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                     <Route path='/projects' component={Projects}/>
                  </Switch>
              </BrowserRouter>
           </div>
        );
    }
};
```

And then I have these components that I'm trying to route to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentBox from './contentBox.jsx';

class Home extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Välkommen</h1>
        );
    }
};

export default Home;

import React from 'react';
import ContentBox from './contentBox.jsx';

class Projects extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Projekt</h1>
            //<ContentBox text="Projekt vettu"/>
        );
    }
};

export default Projects;
```

I expect the home-component to render on / and the projects-component on /projects. But nothing of that renders inside of the base-component. However, if I remove the 'exact' attribute in the home-route. The home-component will render, but then it also renders on /projects and the projects-component does not render at all.

How come?

I also tried with rendering the projects-component on the /-path (home) and it does render then. So it seems like there is nothing wrong with the components; it must be the routing and I cannot understand why.

Does anyone got an idea?

Comment: All components wrapped by `Route` should be passed a set of `props` – `match`, `location`, and `history`. Can you log those three `props` and see what they're giving you? It sounds like the routes aren't matching. For reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props

Comment: Yes, after getting the history prop in the app - I could see that the url was not what I thought at first. it was not only "/home" and "/projects"; it was "appName/web/home" and "appName/web/projects"! Thank you for leading me there.

Comment: Ah ha! Yep, when there's an issue with matching routes, it's usually that the URL you think is getting passed in is not getting passed in. Good luck!